# BRAOfficeDocumentPackage undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

As a Beginner in swift/ios development I am currently trying to install this library https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter in my swift code I followed the steps indicated there for linking a bridging header to swift however BRAOfficeDocumentPackage is still an undeclared type. Is there something not clear or missing in the instructions?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, can you add it here, such as by answering your own question, or editing your question? I am opening a bounty for your question because I'm seeing the same issue with Xcode 7.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson did you add ` #import "XlsxReaderWriter-swift-bridge.h"` to your bridging header?

Comment: @JAL Yes. I eventually got it working, essentially by trial and error. See my answer below with a link to a git repo. I'm seeking an answer for why the README didn't work as is, and ideally how to fix the README.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a solution. I had the same problem and determinted that it was due to the bridging header not being read, and being silently skipped.

I solved it this way: wherever I had added "Release" settings, I added the same "Debug" settings.

My steps and demo project are here:
https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/demo_swift_excel_xlsx_reader_writer

I am copying my README.md here so it's searchable here.

---

## Demo Swift Excel Xlsx Reader Writer

[XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter) is an Objective-C library that works with Excel OpenXml files (XLSX).

### To create this demo

Create a new project.

Get the repository:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter.git
```

We put the repository in the same folder as our demo project's xcodeproject:

```
Demo Swift Xsls Reader Writer/XlsxReaderWriter
```

Add XlsxReaderWriter.xcodeproj to your project.

Add dependency:

- Targets -> Demo -> Build Phases -> Target Dependencies
- Add XslxReaderWriter -> XslxReaderWriter

Link binaries:

- Targets -> Demo -> Build Phases -> Link Binaries With Libraries.
- Add `libXlsxReaderWriter.a`.
- Add `libz.tbd`. This is more current than what the official doc says, which is to add the older version named `libz.dylib`.

Linking:

- Project -> Demo -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
- -> (Debug & Release) -> (+) -> Any Architeture | Any SDK
- Add: `-all_load`

Search Paths:

- Project -> Demo -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> User Header Search Paths
- -> (Debug & Release) -> (+) -> Any Architecture
- Set it to: `$(SRCROOT)/XlsxReaderWriter/` not `$(SRCROOT)/XlsxReaderWriter/XlsxReaderWriter/`.
- Select "recursive".

Bridging Header:

- Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select “Source” and click “Header File“.
- We like the file name `Bridge.h`
- Add this text: `#import "XlsxReaderWriter-swift-bridge.h"`

Add the bridge:

- Project -> Demo -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header
- -> (Debug & Release) -> (+) -> Any Architecture | Any SDK -> Add: `Bridge.h`

Verify:

- Run the project.
- It should compile and launch a blank simulator.

### To load an Excel file

Create an Excel file by using your own Excel software, or any Excel-compatible software.

- For example, create `DemoWorkbook.xlsx` and save it in the repository.
- For example, in the cell A1, type the word "Alpha".

Edit `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let documentPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DemoWorkbook", ofType: "xlsx")!
    let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(documentPath)
    let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
    let string: String = worksheet.cellForCellReference("A1").stringValue()
    print(string) // The Xcode console should now show the word "Alpha"
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

}
```

Verify:

- Run the project.
- It should compile and launch a blank simulator.
- The Xcode console should now show the word "Alpha".

Comment: Being new to SO I'm trying to figure out why you set a bounty on someone else's question and then answered it with an amazing question yourself. I've never seen this does before. Is it to give the question exposure? But why would you use your own rep for a bounty? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it's a great community. Yes, you're correct, it is to give the question exposure, because my answer works for me but perhaps not of the original poster, or for other people. I use my rep for a bounty because I believe in helping people. :)

Comment: lol That's cool. I guess it's the SO version of philanthropy. I'll be sure to remember that when my rep is at a level where I don't have to worry about hitting zero since so many members jump at the opportunity to hit that DV button ;) Thanks @joelparkerhenderson